# How to highlight values that are in all columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula, conditional-formatting, gs-conditional-formatting

I need to highlight a value if it appears in all columns of a spreadsheet.  Essentially I'm going through failing test results and comparing them with the previous three days of data.  I would like an easy way to highlight if it's failed 4 out of 4 times, or 3 out of 4 times.

```
- Test 1       Test 2       Test 3       Test 4   ...
- Test 1       Test 3       Test 4       Test 5   ...
- Test 1       Test 3       Test 4       Test 6   ...
- Test 1       Test 2       Test 3       Test 6   ...
```

In the above lists I would want Tests 1 and 3 highlighted red and Test 4 highlighted yellow.

Using either Excel or Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

I've chosen Excel (since easier to parse the sample!). Please select your data array (4x4 in this case - assumed to start in A1) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$D$4,A1)=4
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red formatting, OK, OK.

Then repeat the above but change the final `4` to `3` and select yellow.

---

For Google Spreadsheets the formulae are the same but after selecting A1:D4, Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., Custom Formula is, etc, then finish with <kbd>Done</kbd>.